# How do I toggle Jquery validation using Ignore attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a panel which is toggled visible/invisible on clicking a button.
Say the panel has extra fields, I'd like to turn off validation on those fields when the panel is hidden, but turn them back on when shown.

I've seen the 'Ignore' option of the Jquery validation plugin, but I'm wondering how I'd go about re-enabling it after the panel is shown again.

Comment: What validation plugin are you using? Is this strictly client-side code or is it bound to server as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you could use `addClass/removeClass` when the panel is visible/hidden respectively?

Comment: i think this is a good solution.  see the comments in the answer here for more info on how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379838/using-depends-with-the-jquery-validation-plugin

Comment: I used the Attr("disabled", "true") /  Attr("disabled", "false") as the Jquery validation plugin doesn't validate disabled controls.